# I want to use multiple object domains when querying in the @QueryProjection annotation of QueryDsl

Tags: spring-boot

I know there are several ways to projection in querydsl.

Like this Projection.bean, Projection.field, Projection.construtor.

But I want to do @QueryProjection annotation but it doesn't work.

The created Entity and Dto classes are as follows.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(length = 64)
    private String email;
    
    @Column(length = 64)
    private String name;
    
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
    
    @Column
    private Date updateDateTime;
    
    @Column
    private Date createDateTime;        

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDto {
    
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String email;
    
    private AddressDto address;
    
    @QueryProjection
    public UserDto (Long id,String name,String email,Address address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

It is the query code that has a problem, but it is as follows.

```
public List<UserDto> getUser(UserDto dto) {
    return queryFactory
            .select(new QUserDto(user.id,user.name,user.email, user.address))
            .from(user)
            .fetch();       
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help with it.